# Ant delete task

Tags: ant

I have several files with name abc* and i want to delete all those files. is it possible using ant task. For eg. my directory structure is:

c:\
   myapp\
       abc.xml
       abc.txt
       abc-1.2.xml
       abc-abc.xml
       abcdef.xml
       pqr.xml
       xyz.xml
       abc\

so from this, i need to delete all abc* files. So if i use ant it should delete following:
       abc.xml
       abc.txt
       abc-1.2.xml
       abc-abc.xml
       abcdef.xml

it should leave directory with abc*

Can somebody help me.

Almas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<target name="testingdelete" >
<delete>
    <fileset dir="." includes="**/abc*"/>
  </delete>
</target>
```

should work.

It deletes all files with abc* and leaves behind directories named abc. It will delete from all sub-directories as well.